# React WordPress Customizer custom control

Tags: reactjs, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I am just doing a demo on the WordPress customizer API to edit the header with custom control.

I have designed a custom control by extending WP_Customize_Control and Jquery to refresh the element, which is working fine.

When I compared this with react based Customizer which is much faster than PHP/JQuery based.

Is there any starter example/doc to start working with React-based customizer controls etc.